# How to select JSON array (JSON substring) in JasperReport with JSONQL?

Tags: json, jasper-reports

I want to create a report using Jaspersoft Studio with a json file as datasource. I want to select some fields from this json and also a substring of the original json. This should be done by jsonql.

First, an example with the "JSON language" in JasperSoftStudio:
[image: JSON query]

gives the following result:
[image: data preview JSON]

This is exactly what I want to have, the delivery note number as a field, and the barcodes as an array of objects / json substring.

What I am not able to do is, to achieve this with jsonql. The following query

[image: jsonql query]

gives the result

[image: jsoql data preview]

The following json was used for this example

```
{
"tour": {
    "shipments": [
        {
            "containers": [
                {
                    "boxes": [
                        {
                            "customerModule": "DEFG",
                            "deliveryDateTime": "2022-04-25 11:49:24.834000",
                            "boxNumber": 2
                        },
                        {
                            "customerModule": "ABCD",
                            "deliveryDateTime": "2022-04-25 11:50:24.810000",
                            "boxNumber": 1
                        }
                    ],
                    "licensePlate": "123"
                }
            ],
            "deliveryNoteNumber": "6785000",
            "barcodes": [
                {
                    "content": "barcode_01_04"
                },
                {
                    "content": "barcode_03_04"
                },
                {
                    "content": "barcode_04_04"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "containers": [
                {
                    "boxes": [
                        {
                            "customerModule": "ZXYV",
                            "deliveryDateTime": "2022-04-25 11:51:24.834000",
                            "boxNumber": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "customerModule": "UHGI",
                            "deliveryDateTime": "2022-04-25 11:52:24.834000",
                            "boxNumber": 2
                        }
                    ],
                    "licensePlate": "987"
                }
            ],
            "deliveryNoteNumber": "6785001",
            "barcodes": [
                {
                    "content": "Barcode_01_04"
                },
                {
                    "content": "Barcode_02_04"
                },
                {
                    "content": "Barcode_04_04"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "handlingDateTime": "2022-04-25 11:50:24.883000"
}
```

I tried to use this [documentation](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jsonqldatasource/index.html), but I could not get it working.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? To display the barcodes along with the deliveryNoteNumber?

Answer (score 0):

The JSONQL data source doesn't properly convert arrays to Strings for some reason.

What you can do is change the `barcodes` field from `java.lang.String` to `java.lang.Object`.  You can do that by clicking Edit in the Fields tab and changing the Class Type for the field.

With `java.lang.Object` as field type, the field value will be the underlying JSON (Jackson) model array object.  You can do `$F{barcodes}.toString()` if you need to explicitly convert it to a String in an expression.